# How to promote two different urls having the same content with different language?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, multilingual

I am facing this issue for my client website. I am having different URLs has the same content with different language? Example:

url1: `http://www.site1/abc-cde.html`
url2: `http://www.site1/fgh-ijk.html`

Here I have two URLs but the language of first URL is English, second one is French. Both are having same content but different language.

Does here a duplicate issue occur or not? And how to promote these pages based on the language? If anyone is searching French means that page only come so what to do for that one?

Answer (score 1):

When you have language alternate pages, **that is not duplicate content**. That is unique content on different language. But, to be on the same page with search engine and to help them better understand your content, you can create language annotations. Every page should have self referring `hreflang` and `hreflang` of alternate page in second language.

For example:

**English page should have:**

```html
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.site1/abc-cde.html" hreflang="en" />

<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.site1/fgh-ijk.html" hreflang="fr" />
```

**French page should have:**

```html
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.site1/fgh-ijk.html" hreflang="fr" />

<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.site1/abc-cde.html" hreflang="en" />
```

There are few ways to accomplish this. The easiest way is to use your Sitemap. Full explanation can be found at following link:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en

How to create multi language sitemap you can see here:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2620865?hl=en